# Removing whitespace from strings

Tags: java, parsing, whitespace

I'm working on a parsing assignment, and I'm supposed to take the input and turn it into two separate strings and output the strings. If there is no comma, I give an error message. If the choice is "q", then end the loop. Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.*;

public class ParseStrings {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);

      /* Type your code here. */
      String name;
      String first;
      String last;
      int commaIndex;
      int size;
      boolean quit = false;
      
      while (!quit)
      {
         System.out.println("Enter input string:");
         name = scnr.nextLine();
         commaIndex = name.indexOf(',');
         size = name.length();
         
         // get q case
         if (name.equals("q"))
         {
            quit = true;
         }
         
         // if no comma, give error message
         else if (commaIndex == -1)
         {
            System.out.println("Error: No comma in string.");
            System.out.println();
         }
         
         else
         {
            first = name.substring(0, commaIndex);
            last = name.substring(commaIndex + 1, size);
            
            // re do, but without spaces 
            
            first = first.replaceAll(" ", "");
            last = last.replaceAll(" ", "");
            commaIndex = name.indexOf(',');
            first = name.substring(0, commaIndex);
            last = name.substring(commaIndex + 1, size);
            
            System.out.println("First word: " + first);
            System.out.println("Second word: " + last);
            System.out.println();
         }
      }
   }
}
```

And the input is this:

```
Jill, Allen
Golden , Monkey
Washington,DC
q
```

I'm not getting the points because of the space after the word "Golden " and before " Monkey"

Comment: You correctly replace the white spaces but afterwards overwrite your correct result ... See `commaIndex = name.indexOf(',');` and the next two lines, just before console printing.

Comment: @E.Körner yup, thank you so much! I was thinking that I would have to re-do it because the strings now do not have the whitespace, so I would have to find the index of the comma for the newly modified string. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
  /* Type your code here. */
  String name;
  String first;
  String last;
  
  while (true)
  {
     System.out.println("Enter input string:");
     name = scnr.nextLine();

     // get q case
     if (name.equals("q"))
     {
        //You can avoid to use quit flag, you can break the loop
       break;
     }
     else
     {

        //Separate the input with split by the comma character
        string [] arr = name.split(",");

         // if no comma, give error message in other words if you array is empty
        if(arr.length==0){
        System.out.println("Error: No comma in string.");
        System.out.println();
        }

        //check if you have more than 2 words
        if(arr.length>1){
            //the trim function will remove all white spaces at the start and end of the string
            first = arr[0].trim();
            last = arr[1].trim();
        System.out.println("First word: " + first);
        System.out.println("Second word: " + last);
        System.out.println();
        }else{
            first =arr[0].trim();
            System.out.println("First word: " + first);
            System.out.println();
        }

     }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `String.split(String)` it takes a regular expression. Split on optional whitespace and comma. Like,

```
String[] tokens = name.trim().split("\\s*,\\s*");
String first = tokens[0];
String last = tokens[tokens.length - 1];
```